Removing duplicate number sets from a table
I am trying to find out how I can see in my table where the same set of numbers appears.
Eg. I have a table with 10 columns numbered 1 -10.
each column has a different number from 1 - 10.
I want to see if there is the same number set in any rows.
Eg.
Row 1 : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Row 2 : 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1
These are different but they have the same numbers in them so I want to remove any number sets that are similar in this regard.

Please include a [mre] ; table definitions, data, desired results, etc.  Read more here ; Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Is there a column that holds the identity for these rows or is it just a table of 10 columns?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

@AwaysThatGuy, did you have a chance to try the proposed solutions?

You can you can use a combination of CROSS APPLY, VALUES, and STRING_AGG to unpivot and aggregate the values into a single ordered comma-separated list that uniquely defines the set.
From there, you can use a COUNT(*) window function to count the duplicates, ROW_NUMBER() to number the duplicates, and even DENSE_RANK() to number the distinct sets. One or more of these values can be used to filter the results as desired.
WITH CombinedValues AS (
    SELECT
        D.*,
        VL.ValueList,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY VL.ValueList) AS SetNumber,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY VL.ValueList) AS DupCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VL.ValueList ORDER BY D.Id) AS RowNum
    FROM Data D
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(V.Value, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY V.Value) AS ValueList
        FROM (
            VALUES
                (Col1), (Col2), (Col3), (Col4), (Col5),
                (Col6), (Col7), (Col8), (Col9), (Col10)
        ) V(Value)
    ) VL
)
SELECT *
FROM CombinedValues CV
--WHERE CV.DupCount >= 2 -- Uncomment to only show the duplicates
--WHERE CV.RowNum = 1    -- Uncomment to only show The first of each distinct set
ORDER BY ValueList

Sample results (with some extra test data):



Id
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
Col6
Col7
Col8
Col9
Col10
ValueList
SetNumber
DupCount
RowNum




1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1
2
1


2
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1
2
2


5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
6
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6
2
1
1


3
5
6
5
6
5
6
5
6
5
6
5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6
3
2
1


4
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6
3
2
2



If duplicate values are present within a set, two sets must have the same number of each value to be considered a match. If you only care about distinct values, you can modify the above query with:
...
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Distinct values
        SELECT STRING_AGG(DV.Value, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DV.Value) AS ValueList
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT Value
            FROM (
                VALUES
                    (Col1), (Col2), (Col3), (Col4), (Col5),
                    (Col6), (Col7), (Col8), (Col9), (Col10)
            ) V(Value)
        ) DV
    ) VL
...

Results:



Id
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
Col6
Col7
Col8
Col9
Col10
ValueList
SetNumber
DupCount
RowNum




1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1
2
1


2
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1
2
2


3
5
6
5
6
5
6
5
6
5
6
5,6
2
3
1


4
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
5,6
2
3
2


5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
6
5,6
2
3
3



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Adapted this solution Select rows with the same set regardless of the order
to your example.
WITH CTE as
(
  select *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rn
  From Example
)
select t.*
from CTE t
where NOT exists (
    select 1
    from CTE t1
    where 
        t.rn<>t1.rn
        and t1.Col1 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col2 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col3 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col4 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col5 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col6 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col7 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col8 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col9 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
        and t1.Col10 in (t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,t.Col4, t.Col5, t.Col6, t.Col7, t.Col8, t.Col9, t.Col10)
)

fiddle

Since your values are in the range 1-10 you can sum the power of 2 and simple "group by having":
with data(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) as (
    select 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 union all
    select 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1 
)
select string_agg(id, ',') as ids from (
    select id, sum(val) as val from (
        select id, col, power(2,val-1) as val from data
        unpivot (
            val for col in (
            col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
            )
        ) p
    ) t
    group by id
) t
group by val having(count(*) > 1)
;


I do not see how this works. I tried to create a fiddle for it with more example records: https://dbfiddle.uk/vnQc3Kuq


I am trying to find out how I can see in my table where the same set
of numbers appears.

Here is another generic method to see where the same set of numbers appears across the columns. The number of columns is irrelevant.
It is leveraging SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
order by clause inside the FLWOR expression does all the magic.
After that you can apply your favorite method to remove duplicates by using calculated column token.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT, col4 INT, col5 INT,
    col6 INT, col7 INT, col8 INT, col9 INT, col10 INT
);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- just to see
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(XMLData);

-- real deal
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    ).query('
      for $x in /root/*[local-name()!="id"]/text()
      order by xs:int($x)
      return data($x)
   ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1024)')) AS t1(token);

Output



id
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6
col7
col8
col9
col10
token




1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


2
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10



